# Google API v2 -

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-oauth

**Hi everybody,**

well, here it is my problem.

I have a corporation gmail user, lets say **developer-user@mycompany.com**, and I would like to list all the gsheets I have in my gdriver trhough the google API for Java applications, so I generated the credentials I supposed to need:

1. the email, which was auto-created by google with a different domain,
   in this case something like **1234567890@developer.gserviceaccount.com**
2. then I created the p12 key file.

After that I tried the connection and everything ran fine, but It did not list the spread sheets I had, and I figured out that I can not list all the gsheets I had 'till I shared them with the **1234567890@developer.gserviceaccount.com** mail/user, but the problem is that I can NOT share anything outside of the @mycompany.com domain, even though the email (*1234567890@developer.gserviceaccount.com*) created for the authentication is linked to my *developer-user@mycompany.com* account.

I am not sure if I was clear enough, but what I need is a solution for that. did someone figur out something? may you help me?

Anyway, thank you guys and I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to ask your Google Apps Admin to enable sharing outside your domain on Google docs, that's the **only way** Drive will allow the service account to reach existing docs.

The only alternative is to recreate the docs using the service account (programatically) and share them with your account.

Comment: but the actual issuexis that hes using domain level access when a simple regular 3legged oauth would work fine.

Comment: i agree it's not ideal, but if you use their toys you have to abide by their rules.

Answer (score 0):

Your admin can delegate domain wide access to your app which will then be able to impersonate you.

Alternatively, don't use service accounts and simply generate a refresh token for your own account (which is by far the easiest solution).